# Cómo convertir archivo csv delimitado por comas en listas en python

Tags: python

necesito convertir los datos en columnas de un csv en listas independientes (en python)y no sé cómo hacerlo. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias y un saludo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). ¿Has intentado algo por tu cuenta? Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.7
    Puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
import csv

with open('ruta_del_archivo.csv', 'r') as archivo:
    leer = csv.reader(archivo)
    lista = list(leer)
    print(lista)
```

Modo    Descripción

- 'r'  abrir archivo para leer
- 'w'  abrir archivo para escribir...

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/open